# How can I connect those pins to jumper wires?

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, breadboard, pins, nrf24l01

I have an nRF24L01 and I want to connect these pins with jumper wires to my Arduino but the module covers the right side of the pins and I can't connect jumper wires to them. How can I connect those pins to jumper wires?

[image]

Comment: They're all shorted to the pins next to them anyway, if you put it into the breadboard like that.

Comment: There are adapters that make these ESP-01 modules breadboard-friendly. Do a search for "ESP-01 breadboard adapter".

Comment: Use a DIP-8 and solder a 8 socket between pins just above. The dip can be inserted into the breadboard. It is very easy ...    This kind but 8 pins https://www.mouser.be/ProductDetail/Harwin/M20-7870442?qs=pYcASEcTDE4HEQ24JqiJCg%3D%3D or this https://www.digikey.be/nl/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/2314826-8/11503289?utm_adgroup=Connectors%2C%20Interconnects&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Supplier_TE%20Connectivity&utm_term=&productid=11503289&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8Me-sdvn-QIVKo9oCR1zBQvcEAQYAyABEgJMAvD_BwE Just fold a little the pins.

Answer (score 2):

This DIY [site](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-wireless-communication-nrf24l01-tutorial/) shows header jumpers with the PCB resting in the slot between them with some plastic spacer for support.

[image]